# Wildcard in Kibana Elasticsearch not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to wildcard `play.google.com` like this

```
 {
  \"value\": \"play.google.com*\",\n" +
  \"type\": \"wildcard\",\n" +
  \"internal\": true\n" +
 }
```

I'm using Google Account Activity to record my urls.
When I open an app via Google playstore, I am able wildcard the entries. 
But when I open an app in my android, the url is like:
`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube`
which is not included in wildcard.

I also tried `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details*`.
But still no luck to avoid App openings.

Please help I'm new with Elastic Search Kibana.

Comment: Can you add your mapping and full query

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mapping issue. [Wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#query-dsl-wildcard-query) is a term-level query, which means the requested field should be a keyword type.

So, you have to provide a mapping for this field to specify that it is a keyword type. You can specify that [at the index creation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#create-mapping) or with [a template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html#indices-templates)

Comment: but for other urls, like www.dropbox.com, is working